# custom toast include with activity or a function in android

Tags: android, toast

i want to make custom toast where it will popup seekbar after clicking button.

the seekbar in custom toast is appear but the progress of the seekbar cannot be moved.

this is how it appears

[image]

for the code, this is the activity for seekbar.

```
 package com.example.froyo2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BloodpressureActivity extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener{
    private SeekBar bar; // declare seekbar object variable
    // declare text label objects
    private TextView textProgress,textAction;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bloodpressure);


    bar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

    textProgress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewProgress);
    textAction = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewAction);
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {

    // change progress text label with current seekbar value
    textProgress.setText("The value is: "+progress);        
    Toast.makeText(this, "Progress: " +progress, 2500).show();
    // change action text label to changing
    textAction.setText("changing");     
}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    textAction.setText("starting to track touch");
}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    seekBar.setSecondaryProgress(seekBar.getProgress());
    textAction.setText("ended tracking touch"); 
}
}
```

this is the listener for the button, where it will appear the custom toast after clicking the button.

```
public void onClick(View v){        
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bloodpressure, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1));
    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setView(layout);
    toast.show();

}
```

Comment: You can't click that `Toast`, a `Toast` is a simple view that is shown to the user without interaction, it's not meant for what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Toasts cannot receive touch events. Remove the Toast part of your code and add the View directly to the Activity's content.

```
LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)
    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

ViewGroup mViewGroup = (ViewGroup) 
    findViewById(android.R.id.content);

View mView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout,
    mViewGroup, false);

mViewGroup.addView(mView);
```